# Ubuntu 20.4 no sound

Tags: sound

I have seen seen several similar issues but none of the situations or answers quite fit.  I seem to have a device and driver OK but no output.  System is an iMac. Here is what alsamixer shows...

Comment: Please edit your question and put in the also mixer results.  I think that the audio people in the ubuntu world are working hard now to resolve some issues.  I am in Kubuntu and things are coming and going from an audio perspective.  Add more detail to your question as well.  I highly recommend installing Pulse Audio Volume Control and studying the outputs to further troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried posting a screenshot of the alsamixer but it doesn;t show?

Comment: I have pulse volume ctl.  It shows speakers a s selection but gives no output.  My  only sound out is via bluetooth.  Sound jack nothing as well.

Comment: Temporary solution. Since sound works with bluetooth I just paired it with a local Echo Dot.  Not the ideal solution but whatever works :-)